# Does the poll phase manages the assignment and execution of requests?

Tags: node.js, event-loop, libuv

I was learning about the event loop. I was confused whether the poll phase performs both the operations as mentioned below or any one.And if not the which phase does it?

1) decide whether a request will go to the thread pool or the OS KERNEL.

2) handling call backs of the above requests

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I got to know that there are seperate API's to handle whether a request will go to the thread pool or os kernel.

And only the callbacks are handled in the poll phase.